# Add prefix in xml serialize object

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, serialization

i am new in XML i want this type of output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>;
    <image:image>
    <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>;
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
    <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>;
    </image:image>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

for that i have created Sitemap.cs class

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "urlset", Namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")]
public class Sitemap
{
    public Sitemap()
    {
        Urls = new List<SitemapUrl>();
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "url")]
    public List<SitemapUrl> Urls { get; set; }
}
```

and my Sitemapurl.cs class is like this

```
[Serializable]
public class SitemapUrl
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "loc")]
    public string UrlLocation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "lastmod")]
    public string LastModificationDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "changefreq")]
    public string ChangingFrequency { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "priority")]
    public float Priority { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "image")]
    public List<Image> ImageList { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
[XmlType("image")]
public class Image
{
    //required
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "loc")]
    public string UrlLocation { get; set; }

    //optional
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "caption")]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    //optional
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "geo_location")]
    public string GeoLocation { get; set; }

    //optional
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    //optional
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "license")]
    public string License { get; set; }
}
```

and my code for create xml and add data in xml is

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("sitemap.xml");
                XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(path);
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
                 new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Sitemap));
                XmlSerializerNamespaces nameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                nameSpace.Add("image", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1");

                nameSpace.Add("video", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1");

                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);


                writer.Serialize(file, sitemap, nameSpace);


                file.Close();
```

using this i got this type of output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>

    <image>
      <loc>http://example.com/image.jpg/</loc>

    </image>
  </url>
```

so how can i add prefix image in image tag??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the namespace corresponding to the `"image"` prefix to the [`XmlElementAttribute.Namespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute attached to the `ImageList` property:

```
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "image", Namespace = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1")]
    public List<Image> ImageList { get; set; }
```

Doing so sets the the namespace assigned to the XML element that results when the class is serialized.  Since you mapped the namespace `"http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"` to the `"image:"` prefix during serialization, that's what will appear.

For further reading, see [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Great, this is the best answer of all I've seen.